# A loop that works for uint64 and uint32 doesn't work for uint8 or uint16

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, uint32

I came up with a loop using bitwise operation, resulting in a number that has every other bit turned on (i.e. in case of 8-bit, 01010101).

In theory, my loop should work just fine, and it does work fine with `uint32` and `uint64`, but not `uint8` or `uint16`. I wonder why...

Here's the code:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // a = 00000000
    uint32 a = 0;
    // b = 11111111
    uint32 b = ~a;
    // a = 11111111
    a = ~a;

    // if (a = 01010101) ~a = 10101010, a << 1 = 10101010
    while (~a != (a << 1)) {
        // 1st time: a << 1 = 11111110 = a
        // 2nd time: a << 1 = 11111010 = a
        a = a << 1;
        // 1st time: ~a = 00000001 = a
        // 2nd time: ~a = 00000101 = a
        a = ~a;
        // 1st time: a << 1 = 00000010 = a
        // 2nd time: a << 1 = 00001010 = a
        a = a << 1;
        // 1st time: b ^ a = 11111101 = a
        // 2nd time: b ^ a = 11110101 = a
        a = b ^ a;
    }

    NSLog(@"%x", a);
    NSLog(@"%u", b);



    // Apply the same loop to a bigger scale
    uint64 x = 0x0;
    uint64 y = ~x;
    x = ~x;

    while (~x != (x << 1)) {
        x = x << 1;
        x = ~x;
        x = x << 1;
        x = y ^ x;
    }

    NSLog(@"%llx", x);
    NSLog(@"%llu", x);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some more information as to what isn't actually working?  What output are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks Derek. The above codes are working fine, but if I replace uint32 with uint8 or uint16, the whole code goes into an infinite loop. I don't quite understand why...

Comment: The failure is most likely due to integer promotion for variables smaller than int.

Comment: `~a != (a << 1)` is always true if `a` is of a type smaller than `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. but is it possible to elaborate a little more? I'm new to the scene.. Why is ~a != (a << 1) when it is smaller than int and what does it mean by smaller than int?

Answer (score 1):

By *"smaller than int"* starblue means `sizeof(a) < sizeof(int)`. Because of the [integer promotion rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), types narrower than int are **always** promoted to int before doing operations. For more information read [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/995714)

As a result, if a is `uint8` or `uint16`, **the top bits of `~a` will always be 1** and can never be equal to `a << 1`

For example if a is `uint16`, running a few iterations we have a = 0x5555. After that point

```
(int)a = 0x00005555
    ~a = 0xFFFFAAAA
a << 1 = 0x0000AAAA
```

As you can see, `~a != (a << 1)` and the program will loop forever