# Implicit type promotion rules

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

*This post is meant to be used as a FAQ regarding implicit integer promotion in C, particularly implicit promotion caused by the usual arithmetic conversions and/or the integer promotions.*

Example 1)
Why does this give a strange, large integer number and not 255?

```
unsigned char x = 0;
unsigned char y = 1;
printf("%u\n", x - y);
```

Example 2)
Why does this give "-1 is larger than 0"?

```
unsigned int a = 1;
signed int b = -2;
if(a + b > 0)
  puts("-1 is larger than 0");
```

Example 3)
Why does changing the type in the above example to `short` fix the problem?

```
unsigned short a = 1;
signed short b = -2;
if(a + b > 0)
  puts("-1 is larger than 0"); // will not print
```

(These examples were intended for a 32 or 64 bit computer with 16 bit short.)

Comment: I suggest documenting the assumptions for the examples, e.g. example 3 assumes that `short` is narrower than `int` (or in other words, it assumes that `int` can represent all the values of `unsigned short`).

Comment: Wait a sec the OP is the same guy who answered the question? It says Lundin asked, best answer is Lundin's as well lol

Comment: @savram Yes, the intention is to write a FAQ entry. Sharing knowledge this way is fine for SO - next time you post a question note the checkbox "answer your own question". But of course the question is still treated like any other question and others can post answers too. (And you don't earn any rep from accepting your own answer)

Comment: @savram: It is absolutely fine to share knowledge this way. See [here: self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Neither answer so far mentions the fact that `printf("%u\n", x - y);` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M I changed it to `%d`, happy now? Also, I'd rather not drag the odd "default argument promotions" into this post, they are left out on purpose, not to confuse the reader with language rules of peripheral interest.

Comment: @Lundin No, not happy now. The first code snippet after your edit will print `-1` on most implementations yet you ask "Why does this give a strange, large integer number and not 255?"  This is relevant to the topic because it's a catch-22 of sorts: you can't know what format specifier to use until you understand the promotion rules.

Comment: Nice example is `~((u8)(1 << 7))` to the list.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

C was designed to implicitly and silently change the integer types of the operands used in expressions. There exist several cases where the language forces the compiler to either change the operands to a larger type, or to change their signedness.

The rationale behind this is to prevent accidental overflows during arithmetic, but also to allow operands with different signedness to co-exist in the same expression.

Unfortunately, the rules for implicit type promotion cause much more harm than good, to the point where they might be one of the biggest flaws in the C language. These rules are often not even known by the average C programmer and therefore cause all manner of very subtle bugs.

Typically you see scenarios where the programmer says "just cast to type x and it works" - but they don't know why. Or such bugs manifest themselves as rare, intermittent phenomena striking from within seemingly simple and straight-forward code. Implicit promotion is particularly troublesome in code doing bit manipulations, since most bit-wise operators in C come with poorly-defined behavior when given a signed operand.

---

### **Integer types and conversion rank**

The integer types in C are `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and `enum`.
`_Bool`/`bool` is also treated as an integer type when it comes to type promotions.

All integers have a specified *conversion rank*. C11 6.3.1.1, emphasis mine on the most important parts:

> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
> — No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
> — The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.
> **— The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `signed char`.
>
> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.**
> — The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width.
> — The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char.
> — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
> — The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).

The types from `stdint.h` sort in here too, with the same rank as whatever type they happen to correspond to on the given system. For example, `int32_t` has the same rank as `int` on a 32 bit system.

Further, C11 6.3.1.1 specifies which types are regarded as the *small integer types* (not a formal term):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
> be used:

> — An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.

What this somewhat cryptic text means in practice, is that `_Bool`, `char` and `short` (and also `int8_t`, `uint8_t` etc) are the "small integer types". These are treated in special ways and subject to implicit promotion, as explained below.

---

### **The integer promotions**

Whenever a small integer type is used in an expression, it is implicitly converted to `int` which is always signed. This is known as the *integer promotions* or *the integer promotion rule*.

Formally, the rule says (C11 6.3.1.1):

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.

This means that all small integer types, no matter signedness, get implicitly converted to (signed) `int` when used in most expressions.

This text is often misunderstood as: "all small signed integer types are converted to signed int and all small, unsigned integer types are converted to unsigned int". This is incorrect. The unsigned part here only means that if we have for example an `unsigned short` operand, and `int` happens to have the same size as `short` on the given system, then the `unsigned short` operand is converted to `unsigned int`. As in, nothing of note really happens. But in case `short` is a smaller type than `int`, it is always converted to (signed) `int`, *regardless of it the short was signed or unsigned*!

The harsh reality caused by the integer promotions means that almost no operation in C can be carried out on small types like `char` or `short`. Operations are always carried out on `int` or larger types.

This might sound like nonsense, but luckily the compiler is allowed to optimize the code. For example, an expression containing two `unsigned char` operands would get the operands promoted to `int` and the operation carried out as `int`. But the compiler is allowed to optimize the expression to actually get carried out as an 8-bit operation, as would be expected. However, here comes the problem: the compiler is *not* allowed to optimize out the implicit change of signedness caused by the integer promotion because there is no way for the compiler to tell if the programmer is purposely relying on implicit promotion to happen, or if it is unintentional.

This is why example 1 in the question fails. Both unsigned char operands are promoted to type `int`, the operation is carried out on type `int`, and the result of `x - y` is of type `int`. Meaning that we get `-1` instead of `255` which might have been expected. The compiler may generate machine code that executes the code with 8 bit instructions instead of `int`, but it may not optimize out the change of signedness. Meaning that we end up with a negative result, that in turn results in a weird number when `printf("%u` is invoked. Example 1 could be fixed by casting the result of the operation back to type `unsigned char`.

With the exception of a few special cases like `++` and `sizeof` operators, the integer promotions apply to almost all operations in C, no matter if unary, binary (or ternary) operators are used.

---

### **The usual arithmetic conversions**

Whenever a binary operation (an operation with 2 operands) is done in C, both operands of the operator have to be of the same type. Therefore, in case the operands are of different types, C enforces an implicit conversion of one operand to the type of the other operand. The rules for how this is done are named *the usual arithmetic conversions* (sometimes informally referred to as "balancing"). These are specified in C11 6.3.18:

(Think of this rule as a long, nested `if-else if` statement and it might be easier to read :) )

> 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
> types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
> and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
> explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
> the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
> and complex otherwise. This pattern is called *the usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is float.
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Notable here is that the usual arithmetic conversions apply to both floating point and integer variables. In the case of integers, we can also note that the integer promotions are invoked from within the usual arithmetic conversions. And after that, when both operands have at least the rank of `int`, the operators are balanced to the same type, with the same signedness.

This is the reason why `a + b` in example 2 gives a strange result. Both operands are integers and they are at least of rank `int`, so the integer promotions do not apply. The operands are not of the same type - `a` is `unsigned int` and `b` is `signed int`. Therefore the operator `b` is temporarily converted to type `unsigned int`. During this conversion, it loses the sign information and ends up as a large value.

The reason why changing type to `short` in example 3 fixes the problem, is because `short` is a small integer type. Meaning that both operands are integer promoted to type `int` which is signed. After integer promotion, both operands have the same type (`int`), no further conversion is needed. And then the operation can be carried out on a signed type as expected.

Of note, C++ applies pretty much identical rules.

Comment: *"Whenever a small integer type is used in an expression, it is implicitly converted to int which is always signed."* Could you point to the exact place in the standard that says that it *should* happen? The C11 6.3.1.1 quote says *how* it happens (if it happens) but it doesn't say that it *must* happen e.g., why `x - y` in the question behaves as `(unsigned)(int)((int)x - (int)y)` instead of `(unsigned)(int)((Uchar)((Uchar)x - (Uchar)y))` goo.gl/nCvJy5 . Where does the standard says that if `x` is char then `+x` is `int` (or unsigned)? In c++ it is §5.3.1.7 goo.gl/FkEakX

Comment: @jfs For binary operators where the usual arithmetic conversions apply, the "should" part is included as part of those rules, quoted above. For other operators, they are promoted if the specific operator (chap 6.5) requires it. Take for example the unary `-` operator, 6.5.3.3: "The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.". Another example (special case) is the prefix `++`, which does not mention integer promotion, and therefore its operand is not promoted.

Comment: @Lundin *«the "should" part is included as part of those rules»* I don't see it. Could you provide a specific quote from the standard that says that operands of the **same** small integer type are promoted while performing a binary operation such as `x-y`? (in other words that there is no `(char)-(char)` operator only `(int)-(int)` or wider — It is true as far as I know). c11  6.5.6/4 points to 6.3.1.8/1 which says "the purpose  is to determine common real type" but if operands are already of  the *same* type, it is not explicit that any conversation *should* be performed.

Comment: @jfs "Otherwise, ..." (if neither operand is float type) "...the integer promotions are performed on both operands." . And then afterwards "If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed."

Comment: @Lundin yes, I've seen it and I interpret it the same way but I hoped there is something more explicit: it is clear that **if** the usual arithmetic conversions are performed then the operands such as x,y are *promoted* but it is not very explicit whether the conversions *must* be performed if the operands have the *same* type already.

Comment: @jfs It is perfectly clear to me. 6.5.6/4 explicitly says, black on white in normative text, that the usual arithmetic conversions have to be performed: "If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on them."

Comment: @Lundin yes, I explicitly mentioned it above. The unclear part: "the purpose is to determine the *common real type*" i.e., if the operands *already* have the *same* type then it might be interpreted  that the conversions are a no-op — I know that it is not actually so e.g., `(char)+(char)` is always promoted to `(int)+(int)` (or unsigned).

Comment: "Example 1 could be fixed by casting one or both operands to type unsigned int."  The suggested cast(s) won't yield 255 as the OP expected.  The proper fix is to cast the result of the subtraction back to the `(unsigned char)` that the operands started from, as in `(unsigned char) (x-y)`: this will give the OP the expected 255.  People often fail to appreciate casting to a smaller size, however, this is the proper way to accomplish truncation (which will be followed by implicit/automatic signed or zero extension to ~int size).

Comment: @ErikEidt Yes it would, as you get unsigned int wrap-around and then an implicit conversion back to unsigned char. The danger with casting after the operation is that the bug could already have struck. Suppose for example that you have `x << y` instead. Undefined behavior of shifting beyond the size of `x` could occur and then no cast afterwards will save the program. The pedantic version (MISRA-C compliance etc) will cast both before the operation and afterwards, so that no implicit conversions occur at all.

Comment: 1) The standard quote says *"The rank of any standard integer type shall be **greater than** the rank of any extended integer type with the same width."*. Then *"For example, `int32_t` has the **same rank** as `int` on a 32-bit system."*. 2) *"Example 1 could be fixed by casting **one or both operands** to type **`unsigned int`**."* this won't work.

Comment: @Student 1) The stdint.h aren't the "extended integer types", but rather typedefs corresponding to the standard integer types. "Extended integer types" refers to the case where an implementation (compiler) decides to invent its own integer types - which is allowed. 2) Sure it will, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: 1) While reading the *Integer types and conversion rank* section, after some search I stumbled upon this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011642/] where the OP mentioned *"[...]So the rank of `int32_t` is lower than that of `int`."*. That made me puzzle. 2) I was testing the examples here: https://rextester.com/BUNN55540

Comment: The "whenever" below the heading "usual arithmetic conversions" does not apply to the binary shift operators.

Comment: @RolandIllig The detailed story is that each and every operator chapter in the standard tells explicitly which promotions it uses. The shift ones are indeed among the special cases, that only integer promote the left operand and use the promoted type as the result of the expression.

Comment: @Lundin The types defined by stdint.h may be extended integer types. See C17/C18 footnote 265, C11 footnote 261, or C99 footnote 218: **"Some of these types may denote implementation-defined extended integer types."** Any such types would have lesser rank than a standard integer type of the same width. (An example that springs to mind - if the standard signed types are ones-complement, but there is a special twos-complement keyword to define `int32_t`, etc.)

Comment: (cont.) Although it *would* seem more sensible for `int32_t` to have higher rank than a standard 32-bit, signed, 1's complement integer (since the `int32_t` can represent one more value), the standard ranks them the other way round. It's a good job that WG14 are finally getting rid of non-2's complement signed integers in the next version of the standard!

Comment: I did my best to summarize your answer in a few simple rules and a promotion flow diagram [in my answer I just added here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654668/4561887).

Comment: 6.3.1.1 N1256: "The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
be used: ... If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.
(48) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions" -- where does this say the compiler is required to promote? If I use `a-b` and the types of a,b are `unsigned short`, why are `a` and `b` considered expressions where an `int` "may be used"?

Comment: If that is meant to be the interpretation (all integer types of lower rank than `int` and `unsigned int` are promoted to these, when used in integer arithmetic expressions) it is a *tremendously lousy* way of documenting it in the standard.

Comment: @JasonS It's said in normative text for each operator where it applies, for example 6.5.7 "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands." or 6.5.5 "The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands."

Answer (score 10):

According to the previous post, I want to give more information about each example.

**Example 1)**

```
int main(){
    unsigned char x = 0;
    unsigned char y = 1;
    printf("%u\n", x - y); 
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
}
```

Since unsigned char is smaller than int, we apply the integer promotion on them, then we have (int)x-(int)y = (int)(-1) and unsigned int (-1) = 4294967295.

The output from the above code:(same as what we expected)

```
4294967295
-1
```

**How to fix it?**

I tried what the previous post recommended, but it doesn't really work.
Here is the code based on the previous post:

**change one of them to unsigned int**

```
int main(){
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned char y = 1;
    printf("%u\n", x - y); 
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
}
```

Since x is already an unsigned integer, we only apply the integer promotion to y.  Then we get (unsigned int)x-(int)y.  Since they still don't have the same type, we apply the usual arithmetic converions, we get (unsigned int)x-(unsigned int)y = 4294967295.

The output from the above code:(same as what we expected):

```
4294967295
-1
```

Similarly, the following code gets the same result:

```
int main(){
    unsigned char x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 1;
    printf("%u\n", x - y); 
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
}
```

**change both of them to unsigned int**

```
int main(){
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 1;
    printf("%u\n", x - y); 
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
}
```

Since both of them are unsigned int, no integer promotion is needed.  By the usual arithmetic converison(have the same type), (unsigned int)x-(unsigned int)y = 4294967295.

The output from the above code:(same as what we expected):

```
4294967295
-1
```

**One of possible ways to fix the code:(add a type cast in the end)**

```
int main(){
    unsigned char x = 0;
    unsigned char y = 1;
    printf("%u\n", x - y); 
    printf("%d\n", x - y);
    unsigned char z = x-y;
    printf("%u\n", z);
}
```

The output from the above code:

```
4294967295
-1
255
```

**Example 2)**

```
int main(){
    unsigned int a = 1;
    signed int b = -2;
    if(a + b > 0)
        puts("-1 is larger than 0");
        printf("%u\n", a+b);
}
```

Since both of them are integers, no integer promotion is needed.  By the usual arithmetic conversion, we get (unsigned int)a+(unsigned int)b = 1+4294967294 = 4294967295.

The output from the above code:(same as what we expected)

```
-1 is larger than 0
4294967295
```

**How to fix it?**

```
int main(){
    unsigned int a = 1;
    signed int b = -2;
    signed int c = a+b;
    if(c < 0)
        puts("-1 is smaller than 0");
        printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

The output from the above code:

```
-1 is smaller than 0
-1
```

**Example 3)**

```
int main(){
    unsigned short a = 1;
    signed short b = -2;
    if(a + b < 0)
        puts("-1 is smaller than 0");
        printf("%d\n", a+b);
}
```

The last example fixed the problem since a and b both converted to int due to the integer promotion.

The output from the above code:

```
-1 is smaller than 0
-1
```

If I got some concepts mixed up, please let me know.  Thanks~

Comment: Your fix to Example 2 `signed int c = a+b;` above invokes UB. The resultant type of a+b is unsigned, and the computed value is out of range of a signed integer.

Comment: @Cheshar out-of-range assignment is not UB

Comment: many of the examples in this answer cause UB by using the wrong format specifier, and also it makes an unwarranted assumption about the size of an `int`

Comment: @M.M My bad! Agree, it should have been "_implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal raised_". Signed overflow is UB though. It's easier to lose track of UB/IB.

Comment: @Cheshar: Contrary to myth spread by some compiler maintainers, the Standard's term for actions which should be processed identically by 99.9% of implementations, but which need not be processed meaningfully by implementations where that would be impractical, is "Undefined Behavior".  The term IDB is only used for actions which *all* implementations are supposed to process meaningfully.

Comment: `I tried what the previous post recommended, but it doesn't really work. Here is the code based on the previous post: change one of them to unsigned int`. No, the main answer says: `Example 1 could be fixed by casting the result of the operation back to type unsigned char.` So, they mean to do this, which _does_ work to provide the expected result of `255`!: `printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)(x - y)); // Output: 255`

Answer (score 4):

### Integer and floating point rank and promotion rules in C and C++

I'd like to take a stab at this to summarize the rules so I can quickly reference them. I've fully studied the question and both of the other two answers here, including [the main one by @Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/4561887). If you want more examples beyond the ones below, go study that answer in detail as well, while referencing my "rules" and "promotion flow" summaries below.

I've also written my own example and demo code here: [integer_promotion_overflow_underflow_undefined_behavior.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/integer_promotion_overflow_underflow_undefined_behavior.c).

Despite normally being incredibly verbose myself, I'm going to try to keep this a short summary, since the other two answers plus my test code already have sufficient detail via their necessary verbosity.

### Integer and variable promotion quick reference guide and summary

#### 3 simple rules

1. For any operation where multiple operands (input variables) are involved (ex: mathematical operations, comparisons, or ternary), the variables are *automatically implicitly promoted* as required to the required variable type *before* the operation is performed.

   1. Therefore, you must manually, explicitly *cast the output* to any desired type you desire if you do not want it to be implicitly chosen for you. See the example below.
2. All types smaller than `int` (`int32_t` on my 64-bit Linux system) are "small types". They cannot be used in ANY operation. So, if all input variables are "small types", they are ALL first automatically implicitly promoted to `int` (`int32_t` on my 64-bit Linux system) before performing the operation.
3. Otherwise, if at least one of the input types is `int` or larger, the other, smaller input type or types are automatically implicitly promoted to this largest-input-type's type.

#### Example

Example: with this code:

```c
uint8_t x = 0;
uint8_t y = 1;
```

...if you do `x - y`, they first get implicitly promoted to `int` (which is `int32_t` on my 64-bit
system), and you end up with this: `(int)x - (int)y`, which results in an `int` type with value
`-1`, rather than a `uint8_t` type of value `255`. To get the desired `255` result, **manually**
cast the result back to `uint8_t`, by doing this: `(uint8_t)(x - y)`.

#### Promotion flow

The promotion rules are as follows. Promotion from *smallest to largest* types is as follows.
**Read "`-->`" as "gets promoted to".**

The types in square brackets (ex: `[int8_t]`) are the typical ["fixed-width integer types"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for the given standard type on a typical 64-bit Unix (Linux or Mac) architecture. See, for example:

1. https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)IntegerTypes.html
2. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=platforms-standard-data-types
3. And **even better, test it for yourself on your machine** by running my code here!: **[stdint_sizes.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/stdint_sizes.c)** from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

##### 1. For integer types in 64-bit x86-64 architecture CPUs

Note: *"small types"* = `bool` (`_Bool`), `char [int8_t]`, `unsigned char [uint8_t]`, `short [int16_t]`, `unsigned short [uint16_t]`.

**SMALL TYPES: `bool` (`_Bool`), `char [int8_t]`, `unsigned char [uint8_t]`, `short [int16_t]`, `unsigned short [uint16_t]`**
**--> `int [int32_t]`**
**--> `unsigned int [uint32_t]`**
**--> `long int [int64_t]`**
**--> `unsigned long int [uint64_t]`**
**--> `long long int [int64_t]`**
**--> `unsigned long long int [uint64_t]`**

Pointers (ex: `void*`) and `size_t` are both 64-bits, so I imagine they fit into the `uint64_t` category above.

##### 2. For floating point types

**`float [32-bits]` --> `double [64-bits]` --> `long double [128-bits]`**

### See also

1. https://cppinsights.io/ - a very useful tool which expands your C++ code into exactly what the compiler sees, including after applying all automatic implicit type promotion rules in the compiler.

   1. Ex: see my code [from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76420269/4561887) in CPPInsights.io here: https://cppinsights.io/s/bfc425f6 --> then click the play button to convert and expand it into what the compiler sees, including after applying all automatic implicit type promotion rules.

### Places where I use these rules

1. [How to safely and efficiently find `abs((int)num1 - (int)num2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76420269/4561887)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add two clarifications to @Lundin's otherwise excellent answer, regarding example 1, where there are two operands of identical integer type, but are "small types" that require integer promotion.

I'm using the [N1256 draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) since I don't have access to a paid copy of the C standard.

**First:** (normative)

6.3.1.1's definition of integer promotion isn't the triggering clause of actually *doing* integer promotion. In reality it is 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions.

Most of the time, the "usual arithmetic conversions" apply when the operands are of *different* types, in which case at least one operand must be promoted. But the catch is that for integer types, integer promotion is required in all cases.

> [clauses of floating-point types come first]
>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
> following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

**Second**: (non-normative)

There is an explicit example cited by the standard to demonstrate this:

> EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment
>
> ```
> char c1, c2;
> /* ... */
> c1 = c1 + c2;
> ```
>
> the "integer promotions" require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to `int` size
> and then add the two `int`s and truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two `char`s can be done without
> overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the correct result, the actual execution need only
> produce the same result, possibly omitting the promotions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I'll address the compiler flags you can use to track
down bugs related to implicit type promotion since I just ran into
this "feature". In the following buggy code fragment `exp` is of
type `uint32_t`:

```
for (int32_t i = 22; i >= MAX(22 - exp + 1, 0); i--) {
    ...
}
```

If `exp` < 23 code works fine, if `exp` = 23 loop runs forever, and if
`exp` > 23 loop never runs. The fix is to change the first argument to
`MAX`to `22 - (int32_t)exp + 1`. To make it easier to spot such bugs I
recommend turning on the warning `-Wsign-compare`. It is included in
`-Wextra`, which may be a little heavy for everyday use.

The bug in the other example;

```
unsigned short a = 1;
signed short b = -2;
if(a + b > 0)
    puts("-1 is larger than 0"); // will not print
```

is caught by `-Wsign-conversion`, also included in `-Wextra`. In my
own codebase this flag produces about 40 warnings all of which are
completely benign and not worth the bother to fix.

Unfortunately, neither gcc nor clang has warnings for flagging
"suspicious" type promotions, but leaving safe ones be (e.g `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)`).

You may want to read [Friends don't let friends use
"-W"](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/11/28/206) for (informed) opinion on
when and when not to use the compiler's warning flags.